# Stop buffering data after some time with Media Player

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm using Media Player to streamming. Sometimes because the connection is slow or because others factors the buffering is taken too much time to call the `onPrepared` method. I would like to stop buffering data after some time in Media Player.

For example:

```
public void play() {
     try{
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(source);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // ....
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    // Send a message to activity to end progress dialogue
    sendBufferCompleteBroadcast();
    playMedia();

}
```

What could be the best way to do it?

Comment: Why would you stop buffering? that will unnecessarily make your app seem unresponsive..what particularly you want to achieve?

Comment: It takes a lot time. Sometimes between 20 secs or more.  I want a user too wait so much. Dont worry. I find a way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch something from the Internet? If yes then test your net connection again and again and deliver appropriate Toast if you dont get the proper connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added call the following method after `mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync()`.

```
// Prevent Media Player taking so long time
    private void postDelayed() {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
            }}, 5000);  // 5 seconds

    }
```

If after 5 seconds I don't get a response the `mediaplayer` is reset.